# Screen Flickers Between Video and Login Screen After Reopening Laptop Lid

Tags: video, laptop, screen, lid

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm encountering a perplexing issue on my Ubuntu system that I hope someone can help me troubleshoot. Whenever I'm watching a video in full-screen mode and then close my laptop lid, upon reopening it, the display starts to flicker erratically between the video and the login screen. This creates a confusing situation where it momentarily appears as though my laptop has unlocked itself, leading me to attempt resuming the video, only to realize I'm actually still at the lock screen.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, or does anyone know what might be causing this behavior? I'm looking for any insights or solutions to prevent this screen flickering and ensure a smooth transition back from sleep mode.

```
Ubuntu Product & Version: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4 LTS, 6.5.0-26-generic kernel.

Video Card/GPU Information: Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics card.
Model: Intel Corporation Device a7a1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 50d1
Kernel Module (Driver): The kernel module (driver) in use for my GPU is i915.
```

Thank you for your assistance!